# Azure DevOps warning in DotNetCoreCLI@2 task when running tests

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Recently when I've added the `continueOnError: true` option to the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task(project is based on `.NET 7`) I started monitoring the following warning for which I am wondering is there a way to be removed/suppressed.

```
##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7), 
so if you are using an older Nuget version(and not dotnet cli) to restore, 
then the dotnet cli commands (e.g. dotnet build) which rely on such restored packages might fail. 

To mitigate such error, you can either: 
(1) - Use dotnet cli to restore, 
(2) - Use Nuget version 5.8 to restore, 
(3) - Use global.json using an older sdk version(<=3) to build
```

I have tried specifying `versionSpec: '5.8'` within the `NuGetToolInstaller@1` task as suggested without any success. Now I have decided to use `DotNetCoreCLI@2` for both `restore` and `build` but the `warning` still persists(removed the `NuGetToolInstaller@1` task) as well as adding the `UseDotNet@2` task with `packageType: 'sdk'` and `version: '7.x'` but still no success.

I have tried using `vmImage: 'windows-2019'` as well.

This is how my `.yml` file looks like:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: Use .NET
    inputs:
      packageType: 'sdk'
      version: '7.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore nuget packages'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '$(solution)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build solution'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '$(solution)'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Run tests'
    continueOnError: true
    inputs:
      command: 'test'
      projects: '$(solution)'
      arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Would appreciate any feedback or suggestions, not sure if this `warning` is removeable from my side.

Thank you for your time reading this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested from my side, I can reproduce the issue. When using `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task to run test and there are some failed tests, I can see the warning `##[warning].NET 5 has some compatibility issues with older Nuget versions(<=5.7)...`. If all tests passed, there isn't such warning. It seems to be a problem with the `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task itself.

If you don't want to see this warning, you can try the following workarounds:

1. Run dotnet test command in a [CmdLine@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test) task instead of using `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task. For example:

```
- task: CmdLine@2
  continueOnError: true 
  inputs:
    script: 'dotnet test WebApplicationNet7.sln --logger trx --results-directory $(Common.TestResultsDirectory) --configuration Release'
  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: '*.trx'
    searchFolder: '$(Common.TestResultsDirectory)'
```

2. Use VSTest@3 task to run your test. For example:

```
- task: VSTest@3
  inputs:
    testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
    testAssemblyVer2: |
      **\*test*.dll
      !**\*TestAdapter.dll
      !**\obj\**
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
```

Comment: Thank you, can confirm that the warning is gone using `VSTest@3` task but I think I will stick with `DotNetCoreCLI@2` task for more flexibility and ignore the warning for now.